# When closing Console Window its close the all application

Tags: c#

I'm working with windows form and i have a main **form** and when I click on some button he  open a **console window** that do some work and when its done I want to close the console without closing the all application (main form). I try to close the console with `Environment.Exit(1)` or the function `Destroy()` that belongs to the `Destroy()` and `Create()` the console window. the `Environment.Exit(1)` and  `Destroy()` both close the console but close the form too.
I wonder if there is a way to close only the console without closing the whole application

**EDIT**

```
    private void btSync_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Create();
        ServerSync sycs=new ServerSync();
        Thread sync = new Thread(new ThreadStart(sycs.run));
        sync.Start();
    }
```

The `Create()` open a Console window that run a `Socket()` Thread.

**Problem Solved**
When im start the thread i add to the end of code a `ThreadName.Abort` and outside the thread i check if `ThreadName.IsAlived==false` and inside the if i `Hide()` the console and then `Destroy()` And Its Works!

the `Hide()` method from ***AppDeveloper*** answer.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Please post the code that opens the console window to do some work.

Comment: please post the code for `void main()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `Environment.Exit()` hide the `Console Window`

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr GetConsoleWindow();

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool ShowWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int nCmdShow);

const int SW_HIDE = 0x0;
const int SW_SHOW = 0x5;

public static void HideConsoleWindow()
{
    var handle = GetConsoleWindow();
    ShowWindow(handle, SW_HIDE);

}
```

Comment: But i need to close the console beacuse when the socket close i want to close the Console and let the user open the console again when needed.

Comment: u can close the handle to socket, and clear the console window, it will look new like!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is a console.hide() option? could try that out.

Comment: There isn't. Generally people post answers as answers. If it's a guess maybe just comment :)